# ExtJS 4 Object.prototype fail

Tags: javascript, object, extjs, extjs4, prototype

have a bit problem to use prototype while using `framework ExtJS version 4.1.1.`

At first I made my prototypings before I load ExtJS.
On `"Array.prototype.xyz" and "String.prototype.xyz"` all work fine.
Bot on `"Object.prototype.xyz"` there is a bad behavior in mixin inclusion of `ExtJS`.
Example my test code:

```
Object.prototype.doSomething = function() {
  console.log('I do it!');
}
var a = {};
a.doSomething();
```

Error message from ExtJS:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '$childEls' of undefined
And break.
```

And: 
- Yes. Without "`Uncaught TypeError`: Cannot read property '$childEls' of undefined" it work 
fine.
- No. I use not oter mixins currently.
- Yes. I try to use only one dummy panel Component.

Question: Is there a simple solution to prototype on Object class-object?

Answer (score 0):

The problem stems from one of the fundamental methods of the Ext JS library: `Ext.merge`

Proving this is very simple:

```
Object.prototype.doSomething = function(){ console.log("Does something"); };

var emptyObj = {};
console.log(emptyObj.hasOwnProperty("doSomething"));  // Prints "false"

var mergeObj = Ext.merge({}, {a: "b"});
console.log(mergeObj.hasOwnProperty("doSomething"));  // Prints "true"
```

Basically, every time `Ext.merge` (or `Ext.apply`) is called with an object literal your prototype method is "promoted" up the prototype chain. When you go to create a panel (or any component, really) the class `mixin` object is merged with its prototype's `mixin` object. Since a mixin is defined as an object literal in the class definition, your "doSomething" method is promoted.

Then in `Ext.util.ElementContainer#getClassChildEls`, the `mixin` object is iterated over assuming each property is an existing class and tries to access `mixins[name].self.$childEls` (where `mixins[name]` is your "doSomething" method). Your method doesn't have a `self` property so accessing `$childEls` throws the error.

If you need an object available on every object, write it as a static method like `Object.doSomething` or even `Ext.Object.doSomething`.